# Restrict fiddle.sencha.com the same way as jsfiddle.net

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, jsfiddle

I found out that some questions give links to https://fiddle.sencha.com without any code in the question itself. I will probably vote to close such questions as off-topic, but I suggest we give to **fiddle.sencha.com** the same restriction as **jsfiddle.net** when posting, i.e.:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

---

Edit, also:

- https://www.bootply.com/

Comment: There's probably a long list of external "code paste" sites that should also be restricted in the same way. If someone just dumps a pastebin or whatever link, it's arguably worse than a fiddle.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: We can't just blanket ban all questions with links and text but no code.  Some of those might be valid, if for example a user wants to quote some documentation and then ask a question about it.  I think we should do this on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: @Kevin linking to documentation should be allowed, but I'm referring to known paste dump sites. I'm not talking about blanket banning all links. At best it's someone dumping a JSON or some other data, thinking it's more readable externally. At worst it's a code dump.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: HTTP and HTML are open formats.  Anyone can set up a new paste dump site (or 50) tomorrow, or next week.  It is not feasible to continuously track every paste dump site on the internet.

Comment: @Kevin Dealing the main offenders is probably enough.

Comment: I should mention though that it could be argued there are situations where linking to external information on a dump site is justified, even with little other text/code in the question. I can't think of such an example at the moment though. I'm assuming that such cases are rare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm putting in some more warnings based on [this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352310/1438). My notes:

1. SQL Fiddle includes a schema, sample data and the SQL query. So my warning reads:

   > Please include sample data, the SQL query and a description of the schema in your post. SQL Fiddle is useful for demonstration, but we ask that posts themselves include [complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. Bootply looks pretty much exactly like jsfiddle.net, so we can reuse the same message as we currently use for that site:

   > Please don't use Bootply collaboration links. If the code changes significantly later on, it may be difficult for future readers to follow. 
   > Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead.
3. It seems [fiddle.jshell.net is no longer publicly accessible](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1299). That means many posts are less useful than they would be, which demonstrates the *raison d'être* for discouraging these links. On the plus side, we probably don't need a warning for this site.
4. Plunker looks like Yet Another JSFiddle (YAJSF):

   > Please don't use Plunker collaboration links. If the code changes significantly later on, it may be difficult for future readers to follow. 
   > Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead.
5. Same with Sencha Fiddle:

   > Please don't use Sencha Fiddle collaboration links. If the code changes significantly later on, it may be difficult for future readers to follow. 
   > Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead.

Looking at the rest of the sites, it doesn't seem as if these are actively causing problems right at the moment. Or rather, the number of new post in the last year does not justify the cost of adding another check.

The warnings are now in place:

[image: The edit box turns yellow with a warning icon and text explaining that the OP needs to include the code in their question appears below it. This includes a link to more information.]

Please let me know if they are catching any false positives or if the warnings can be improved.

Comment: Thank you Jon. So the list of similar warned sites will be: **jsfiddle.net, SQLFiddle.com, Bootply.com, JSBin.com, plnkr.co, fiddle.sencha.com, ideone.com, paste.ofcode.org, CodePen.io**. Correct?

Comment: The CodePen.io and ideone.com warnings expired because they weren't getting hit. (This is a feature of our blacklist system to avoid rarely invoked rules from taking resources.) If those are becoming a problem again, I can reinstall the warnings. We also block expirebox.com, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a (partial) list of similar code paste websites. Some of these are from [webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51238). If anyone has run across something not on this list, please leave a comment.

*The items that have strikethrough already have the JSFiddle treatment.*

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ([54,463 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*sqlfiddle.com%22))
- [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/) ([5,678 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.bootply.com%22))
- [fiddle.jshell.net](https://fiddle.jshell.net/) ([4,335 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22fiddle.jshell.net%22))<sup>1</sup>
- <s>[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output) ([2,491 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.jsbin.com%22))</s>
- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit) ([2,032 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.plnkr.co%22))
- [fiddle.sencha.com](https://fiddle.sencha.com) ([1,997 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22fiddle.sencha.com%22))
- <s>[ideone](http://ideone.com/) ([1,031 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.ideone.com%22))</s>
- <s>[paste.ofcode.org](http://paste.ofcode.org) ([224 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22paste.ofcode.org%22))</s>
- <s>[CodePen](http://codepen.io/) ([211 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.codepen.io%22))</s>
- [CSS Desk](http://cssdesk.com) ([66 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.cssdesk.com%22))
- [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) ([17 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.dabblet.com%22)) - *most recent in December 2014*
- [code.reloado.com](http://code.reloado.com/#javascript,html) ([9 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22code.reloado.com%22)) - *most recent in December 2016*
- [Kode Weave](https://mikethedj4.github.io/kodeWeave/editor/) ([9 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22mikethedj4.github.io%2FkodeWeave%22))
- [Coding Ground](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm) ([5 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.tutorialspoint.com%2Fviewproject.php%22))
- [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) ([5 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.dotnetfiddle.net%22)) - *most recent in January 2016*
- [CSS Deck](http://cssdeck.com) ([4 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.cssdeck.com%22)) - *most recent in July 2016*
- [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com) ([4 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.liveweave.com%22)) - *most recent in December 2016*
- [repl.it](https://repl.it/) ([3 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.repl.it%22)) - *most recent in August 2016*
- [Code Envy](https://codenvy.io) ([1 result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22codenvy.io%2F%22)) - *November 2016*

At least the top 7 should get the jsfiddle treatment (which some already have). They are code running websites and just about any time they are linked to from a question, it is somebody showing an example of code that should be in the question itself.

Two more websites that can be misused are:

- [Github Gists](https://gist.github.com/) ([44,742 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22gist.github.com%22))
- [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) ([158 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.pastebin.com%22))<sup>2</sup>

I'm not completely sure on these two because, while they can be used as code dumps, they can also be used to paste other data. I can't think up a scenario at the moment wherein code is unnecessary when linking to them, but it's probably possible.

---

1. For some reason, fiddle.jshell.net is still not being treated as JSFiddle, even though it literally *is* JSFiddle. See [this question](/q/351110/5764553) for previous report that was apparently not acted upon.
2. Links to pastebin.com with no subdomain are treated correctly already

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: [.NETfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: [paste.ofcode.org](https://paste.ofcode.org/)