# Trigger MCVE error on paste.ofcode.org

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, external-links, minimal-reproducible-example

There are [263 posts containing `paste.ofcode.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22paste.ofcode.org%22), some of which are questions not providing any MCVE.

The site itself states *“Your code is always private, and **always expires in one week**.”*. Thus, most shared code has 404’d.

The *“Links to* [site name] *must be accompanied by code.”* error currently doesn’t get triggered for `paste.ofcode.org`. Should we add it?

Comment: It seems that [several have been asked this month](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22paste.ofcode.org%22) (and others may be deleted), so you've got my vote!

Comment: It seems to me that any question with that site in the URL has either got to be deleted because of 'no MCVE' (or another reason that recognizes that the code is not available), or, perhaps, if the question is less than a week old, then the code can be copied from paste.ofcode.org into the question.  Yes, the site should be verboten — or accompanied by the warning.  If the person asking doesn't want their code to survive on SO in perpetuity, they should not be asking the question on SO.

Comment: If it's "always private", how is that even compatible with a CC-by-SA license?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan there's a continuation after that message though, "*Only those that you provide with the URL will be able to access your pasted code within this period.*"

Comment: I'd +1 blacklisting links to the site entirely (if a mere 263 posts warrants that). Links that expire within a week has no place on [se].

Comment: I think that if there is still code in the question, it should not be a problem. As SE code viewer lacks some useful features (line number, nothing more) it can be useful. Just give a warning.

Comment: @user202729 If there’s still code in the question and the question is fine without a link to that paste site, then the link should be removed. There is really *no* reason that a link to a temporary site should be mentioned in a question.

Comment: Looks like it should be added to this list: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352310/171456

Comment: @ZimSystem Oh, there we go! I was wondering whether I’ve already seen such a list, but couldn’t find it!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yeah, there's no good reason to ever post links that'll *intentionally break* here. I've blacklisted the URL pattern with the following message:

> Please avoid links that will intentionally break after a short time; they make these questions and answers less useful to future readers facing similar problems. Placing the code directly into the post ensures that it remains available. See: [How to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Does this apply to answers as well?

Comment: Everything. Questions, answers, comments, titles, flags...

Comment: Nice, that’s even better! Are there other links that produce this or a similar error message?

Comment: Yes, lots. Most URL major URL shorteners, for example.

Answer (score 48):

I don't think users should be allowed to paste this link at all.

It's not even the case "*Links to [site name] must be accompanied by code.*", it's the fact that the link expires and becomes useless garbage in the post - i.e., *whether the post has got the code or not*, the link is useless anyway after a week.

I vote for *blocking* such links *altogether*.