# Please blacklist expirebox.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, external-links, minimal-reproducible-example, content-blocklist

Same reasoning as [Trigger MCVE error on paste.ofcode.org](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365086/trigger-mcve-error-on-paste-ofcode-org): the content of https://expirebox.com is always temporary, and as such has a negative value for Stack Overflow.

Current usage: [80 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aexpirebox.com)

Comment: (_Hey, look! It’s my post linked there!_) There’s also [`hatebin.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22hatebin.com%22), but it’s only been used once (or twice?) so far.

Comment: Where I work, expirebox.com appears to be blocked due to high risks – in addition to the default block of file sharing sites.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is done, more or less [as Joshua suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374497/please-blacklist-expirebox-com/374535#374535) (a link to https://expirebox.com/ works fine, a link to https://expirebox.com/anything will be blocked).

[image: Please avoid links that will intentionally break after a short time; they make these questions and answers less useful to future readers facing similar problems. Placing the code directly into the post ensures that it remains available. See: How to format code]

Comment: Would it be an irritant if someone went ahead and removed these dead links as well?  I don't know that I have the time to do a whole bunch at once, and I would avoid bumping negatively scored/closed posts.

Comment: Knock yourself out, @BSMP; bumping is temporary, dead links are forever an annoyance.

Answer (score 12):

I approve provided the blacklist is `://([^/ ]*\.)?expirebox.com/`. Critically this blocks expirebox links but not the homepage itself. This makes it possible to link to the site itself for discussing it, etc.