# Trigger MRE error on ctxt.io

Tags: feature-request, external-links, minimal-reproducible-example

There are [20 posts containing a link to `ctxt.io`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22ctxt.io%22), some of which are questions not providing any [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The site itself states *“This paste expires in <30 days.”*. Thus, most shared code has 404’d.

The *“Links to* [site name] *must be accompanied by code.”* error currently doesn’t get triggered for `ctxt.io`. Almost 5 years ago, I requested the same thing for a similar site: [Trigger MCVE error on paste.ofcode.org](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365086/4642212). There, Shog9 has added another type of error message that reads:

> Please avoid links that will intentionally break after a short time; they make these questions and answers less useful to future readers facing similar problems. Placing the code directly into the post ensures that it remains available. See: [How to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Please add this or a similar error message to posts that don’t contain code but contain links to `ctxt.io`.

Recent example: the first revision of [How to get specific key value pairs from this array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74968329/1) (now deleted, 10k only).

Comment: Paging Shog9, paging Shog9... does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: I removed some of them. It's not a lot and there's probably more sites like this